# matplotlib "fail to allocate bitmap" after some iterations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't find a solution to avoid this crash.

I have cleaned up the attached code because it contains the issue and nothing else.

Regardless of the size of the image, the program crashes after 368 iterations.

I also tried what I could find in the forums but no solution found ( plt.close('all'), gc. collect().... ).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


compteur = 0
image = cv2.imread(r"D:\OneDrive\Bureau\New folder\12345.jpg")


while True:

    print('1')
    ax_user = plt.imshow(image)

    print('2')
    plt.close('all')

    print (f'\n{compteur}:\t')
    compteur += 1 



367:
1
2

368:
1
Fail to allocate bitmap
```

Comment: convert it to an answer

Comment: I tried to go down the rabbit hole and see why the bitmap fails to be created as it may have to do with a memory leak of some sort, but I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Fail-to-allocate-bitmap-Unable-to-free-colormap-palette-is-still-selected-td13203.html), this is an issue with the TkAgg backend.

> I was able to get it to work using:
>
> ```
> reload(matplotlib)
> matplotlib.use('Agg')
> ```
>
> I'll have to beat on it some more to see if this is robust.
>
> I saw the error message in this code:
>
> http://search.cpan.org/src/NI-S/Tk-804.027/pTk/mTk/win/tkWinDraw.c
>
> ```
> if(!bitmap) {
>     panic("Fail to allocate bitmap\n");
>     DeleteDC(dcMem);
> TkWinReleaseDrawableDC(d, dc, &state);
>     return;
> }
> ```

It is unclear to me why the `bitmap` from that C source code is null, but I've noticed that the Python memory usage keeps increasing with subsequent calls to create another plot/image/figure, regardless of whether one uses `plt.close('all')`, `plt.clf()`, `gc.collect()`, etc, so its failure to be created may have something to do with that. I don't notice the same behaviour with, for example, the Agg backend.

One can read more about backend options in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-builtin-backends), or checking the documentation for `matplotlib.use()`:

> ```
> use(backend, *, force=True)
>     Select the backend used for rendering and GUI integration.
>     
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     backend : str
>         The backend to switch to.  This can either be one of the standard
>         backend names, which are case-insensitive:
>     
>         - interactive backends:
>           GTK3Agg, GTK3Cairo, MacOSX, nbAgg,
>           Qt4Agg, Qt4Cairo, Qt5Agg, Qt5Cairo,
>           TkAgg, TkCairo, WebAgg, WX, WXAgg, WXCairo
>     
>         - non-interactive backends:
>           agg, cairo, pdf, pgf, ps, svg, template
>     
>         or a string of the form: ``module://my.module.name``.
>     
>     force : bool, default: True
>         If True (the default), raise an `ImportError` if the backend cannot be
>         set up (either because it fails to import, or because an incompatible
>         GUI interactive framework is already running); if False, ignore the
>         failure.
>     
>     See Also
>     --------
>     :ref:`backends`
>     matplotlib.get_backend
> ```